# Can't insert values in 1 table

Tags: c#

I have a problem when it comes to inserting table
I have tables Personaldata and Spouse

Insert statement in table Spouse is functioning. however, I cant insert in tables Personaldata.

pls help me.

Here's my code:

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

           personalConn.Open();
           oleDbCmd.Connection = personalConn;

       oleDbCmd.CommandText = "insert into Personaldata(Bloclno,Lotno,Numberofoccupants,Firstname,Familyname,Dateofbirth,Age,Bloodtype,Placeofbirth,Religion) values ('" + this.textBox1.Text + "','" + this.textBox2.Text + "','" + this.textBox3.Text + "','" + this.textBox4.Text + "','" + this.textBox5.Text + "','" + this.textBox6.Text + "','" + this.textBox7.Text + "','" + this.textBox8.Text + "','" + this.textBox9.Text + "','" + this.textBox10.Text + "');";
       oleDbCmd.CommandText = "insert into Spouse(Firstname,Familyname,Dateofbirth,Age,Bloodtype,Placeofbirth,Religion,Startofoccupancy,Contactnumber,NumberofChildren,Numberofdogs, Vaccinatedwithantirabies) values ('" + this.textBox11.Text + "','" + this.textBox12.Text + "','" + this.textBox21.Text + "','" + this.textBox13.Text + "','" + this.textBox14.Text + "','" + this.textBox15.Text + "','" + this.textBox16.Text + "','" + this.textBox17.Text + "','" + this.textBox18.Text + "','" + this.textBox22.Text + "','" + this.textBox25.Text + "','" + this.textBox19.Text + "');";


       int temp = oleDbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: This is not C code. It's C#. Maybe it would work better if you knew what language you were working in. :-) Can you be more specific? "It's not working" is not a valid description of the problem. In what way is it "not working"? Do you get an error message? Does it not compile? Does the Spouse say "Oh no you don't!"? If you want help, be **specific** about the problem you've having. We can't see your screen or read your mind from where we are, so we only know what you tell us.

Comment: **@KenWhite** yes its c#

Comment: As was mentioned in comments to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22277671/976080) you need to give us the text of the error and provide more details of the problem.

Comment: You are re-initializing the oleDbCmd.CommandText to the Spouse query, and not amending to it. That is why only Spouse is getting inserted.

Comment: **@KenWhite** It's working. however When I use to input values for my Spouse and Personaldata tables. I only see values in table Personaldata on the other hand table Spouse have no values though, I inputted values for it..

Comment: **@ray** that's what my problem is. What should I do with it? pls, help me.:(

Comment: You should also be using parameterised queries otherwise you're leaving yourself open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Your question still says "I cant insert", with no explanation of what "can't insert" means. Please read what I wrote in my last comment: **Be specific about the problem you're having**. "I can't insert" is no more a problem description than "It doesn't work**. In what way can you "not insert"? Please [edit] your question and provide specific information about the problem. It's important not only for explaining your immediate problem, but for future readers of this site who find this in a search result when trying to solve **their** problem. SO is not just to provide you with tech support. :-)

Comment: thank you Sir **@KenWhite** but, I already managed it..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way ...
Set `CommandText`, then execute it, then set another `CommandText`, and then execute again!

```
personalConn.Open();
oleDbCmd.Connection = personalConn;

int temp;
oleDbCmd.CommandText = "insert into Personaldata(Bloclno,Lotno,Numberofoccupants,Firstname,Familyname,Dateofbirth,Age,Bloodtype,Placeofbirth,Religion) values ('" + this.textBox1.Text + "','" + this.textBox2.Text + "','" + this.textBox3.Text + "','" + this.textBox4.Text + "','" + this.textBox5.Text + "','" + this.textBox6.Text + "','" + this.textBox7.Text + "','" + this.textBox8.Text + "','" + this.textBox9.Text + "','" + this.textBox10.Text + "');";
temp = oleDbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

oleDbCmd.CommandText = "insert into Spouse(Firstname,Familyname,Dateofbirth,Age,Bloodtype,Placeofbirth,Religion,Startofoccupancy,Contactnumber,NumberofChildren,Numberofdogs, Vaccinatedwithantirabies) values ('" + this.textBox11.Text + "','" + this.textBox12.Text + "','" + this.textBox21.Text + "','" + this.textBox13.Text + "','" + this.textBox14.Text + "','" + this.textBox15.Text + "','" + this.textBox16.Text + "','" + this.textBox17.Text + "','" + this.textBox18.Text + "','" + this.textBox22.Text + "','" + this.textBox25.Text + "','" + this.textBox19.Text + "');";
temp = oleDbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Sir**@Tun Zarni Kyaw* thank you very much.. Finally, It worked..:)

Comment: if it worked, make this one as accepted answer, you will get +2 reputation

Comment: how to do that sir? I am new here

Comment: there is a **tick** symbol at the left side of the answer under the up and down vote buttons ... just click **tick** and make it green

Comment: ok sir thank you.. sir, why is it I cant post anymore a question? what should I do?

Comment: i don't know exactly, if you can do, delete this question you posted ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262634/oledbexception-was-unhandled-syntax-error-into-insert-statement OR edit it to be a clear question

Comment: sir I already deleted the post. but still I can't ask question

Comment: read help page of the stackoverflow OR ask about it in http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: sir **Tun Zarni Kyaw ** I wanna ask if how to display data from MsAccess into datagridview? I have here my code, but its not working. heres my code

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
    
                OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Personaldata", connParam);
    
    
                OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);
    
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    
                dAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataTable.Rows[i][0], dataTable.Rows[i][1], dataTable.Rows[i][2], dataTable.Rows[i][3], dataTable.Rows[i][4], dataTable.Rows[i][5], dataTable.Rows[i][6], dataTable.Rows[i][7], dataTable.Rows[i][8], dataTable.Rows[i][9]);
                }
    
        }

Comment: "I have 9 columns in my table Personaldata"      
"  I got error InvalidOperationException was Unhandled 
(Rows cannot be progmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the  control is data-bound)"
Pls help me, what should I do?

Comment: You dodnt need the for loop. Just dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable; dataGridView1.Databind(); is enough to populate the grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string cT = "insert into Personaldata(Bloclno,Lotno,Numberofoccupants,Firstname,Familyname,Dateofbirth,Age,Bloodtype,Placeofbirth,Religion) values ('" + this.textBox1.Text + "','" + this.textBox2.Text + "','" + this.textBox3.Text + "','" + this.textBox4.Text + "','" + this.textBox5.Text + "','" + this.textBox6.Text + "','" + this.textBox7.Text + "','" + this.textBox8.Text + "','" + this.textBox9.Text + "','" + this.textBox10.Text + "');"+
         "insert into Spouse(Firstname,Familyname,Dateofbirth,Age,Bloodtype,Placeofbirth,Religion,Startofoccupancy,Contactnumber,NumberofChildren,Numberofdogs, Vaccinatedwithantirabies) values ('" + this.textBox11.Text + "','" + this.textBox12.Text + "','" + this.textBox21.Text + "','" + this.textBox13.Text + "','" + this.textBox14.Text + "','" + this.textBox15.Text + "','" + this.textBox16.Text + "','" + this.textBox17.Text + "','" + this.textBox18.Text + "','" + this.textBox22.Text + "','" + this.textBox25.Text + "','" + this.textBox19.Text + "');";

oleDBCmd.CommandText = cT;
```